# Unable open to List in Data Sheet List View

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, datasheet, chrome

I am unable open my list in data sheet list view mode in  Chrome browser but I am able to open in IE.

Does any one know what kind of settings I need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE makes use of a Web Datasheet Component (I believe via an ActiveX control), but Chrome uses "extensions" which are not supported at the moment. Refer to this article: 
http://veroniquepalmer.wordpress.com/2012/02/06/sharepoint-2010-compatibility-with-google-chrome/

Answer (score 1):

Use IE. Datasheet view is only available for IE due to it being one of the few remaining ACtiveX controls, it does not work in the other supported browsers (Firefox/Chrome).

Answer (score 0):

Download the IE based tab extension for CHrome - it will put a button up by the url bar which you can click and it will open an ie tab WITHIN chrome - which will allow you to access datasheet view.